# Descargar tabla html con vba excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, macros

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano.

Estoy intentando descargar una tabla a excel de la página mismarcadores.com.

He conseguido una macro por internet. El problema es que la etiqueta html de la tabla no tiene ID, y siempre que ejecuto la macro salta el siguiente error:

Se ha producido el error 438 en tiempo de ejecución: El objeto no admite esta propiedad o método

La macro que ejecuto es la siguiente:

```
  Public Sub importartblhtml()

    Dim appIE As Object
Dim allRowOfData As Object
Dim curHTMLRow As Object
Dim Fila As Long, Col As Long
Dim Celda As Object

Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE

    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.mismarcadores.com/futbol/espana/laliga/partidos/"

    While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Activate
 Cells.Select
 Selection.ClearContents

    Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementsById("")

    For Fila = 1 To allRowOfData.Rows.Length - 1

        Set curHTMLRow = allRowOfData.Rows(Fila)

        For Col = 0 To curHTMLRow.Cells.Length - 1

            Set Celda = Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila + 1, Col + 1)

            Celda.Value = "'" & curHTMLRow.Cells(Col).innertext

        Next Col

    Next Fila

    .Quit

End With

Set appIE = Nothing
Set curHTMLRow = Nothing
Set Celda = Nothing
End Sub
```

El error salta al ejecutarse la línea

```
Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementsById("")
```

He probado con el método `getElementsByTag("table")(0)`
y tampoco funciona. Importa toda la página excepto lo que quiero, que son los partidos.

No he encontrado mucha información por internet hacerca de como solucionar el error.

El código html de donde quiero sacar los datos es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe si me falta activar alguna referencia o algún otro método para poder descargar esta tabla??

Gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, la parte de código html de la página web, ponla como texto, no como imagen

Answer (score 1):

Puede copiar pegar el "outerHtml" de la tabla del torneo con el ID (Perdón por mi español)

**id**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Muestra:**

[image: Muestra]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub importartblhtml()
    Dim appIE As Object, ws As Worksheet, hTable As Object, clipboard As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.mismarcadores.com/futbol/espana/laliga/partidos/"

        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set hTable = .document.getElementById("#fs-fixtures")
        .Quit
    End With
    With ws
        .Cells.ClearContents
        Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
        'Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Referencias:**

1. Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

Comment: Hola QHarr. Gracias por tu respuesta. Perdón por tardar en responder, pero estaba trabajando. Me aparece un error en la línea New MSForms.DataObject. La referencia que pones se llama exactamante así?? porque la he buscado pero no la encuentro. Saludos.

Comment: Puede añadir un userform al proyecto para obtener la referencia 
automáticamente

Comment: o Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")